# Extra data : error while analysing tweets in json format

Tags: python, json, cloudera, tweepy

Here is my `sentimentMapper.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import tweepy
import json
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler

access_token = ''
access_token_secret = '' 
consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret = ''


 class StdOutListener(tweepy.StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):

        # Parsing 
        decoded = json.loads(data)
        #open a file to store the status objects
        file = open('stream.json', 'w')  
        #write json to file
        json.dump(decoded,file,sort_keys = True,indent = 4)
        #show progress
        print ("Writing tweets to file,CTRL+C to terminate the program")
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print (status)

auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
twitterStream = Stream(auth, StdOutListener())
twitterStream.filter(track=["xx"])
```

The above code was written to collect Twitter data in the form of JSON.

And I used a python script for sentiment analysis based on this post: http://www.alex-hanna.com/tworkshops/lesson-6-basic-sentiment-analysis/

I'm not sure why I am getting the extra data error.
I am using Python 2.6 and cloudera.

Error:

```
Expecting property name: line 1 column 1 (char 1) Extra data: line 1 column 14 - line 1 column 21 (char 14 - 21) Extra data: line 1 column 13 - line 1 column 20 (char 13 - 20) Extra data: line 1 column 12 - line 1 column 47 (char 12 - 47) Extra data: line 1 column 10 - line 1 column 13 (char 10 - 13)

Extra data: line 1 column 10 - line 1 column 15 (char 10 - 15) Extra data: line 1 column 9 - line 1 column 14 (char 9 - 14) Extra data: line 1 column 6 - line 1 column 9 (char 6 - 9) Expecting property name: line 1 column 1 (char 1) Extra data: line 1 column 13 - line 1 column 50 (char 13 - 50) Extra data: line 1 column 14 - line 1 column 70 (char 14 - 70) Extra data: line 1 column 9 - line 1 column 12 (char 9 - 12) Extra data: line 1 column 2 - line 1 column 3 (char 2 - 3) 

Traceback (most recent call last): File "sentimentMapper.py", line 81, in <module> main() File "sentimentMapper.py", line 35, in main if 'text' in data: TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable
```

This how the data looks:

```
{
    "contributors": null,
    "coordinates": null,
    "created_at": "Mon Dec 11 15:09:15 +0000 2017",
    "entities": {
        "hashtags": [],
        "symbols": [],
        "urls": [
            {
                "display_url": "",
                "expanded_url":  "",
                "indices": [
                    37,
                    60
                ],
                "url": ""
            }
        ],
```

Comment: If your data is "too big" then reduce it until you have the minimal needed data reproducing the error.  And please post the full error message __and the traceback__.

Comment: Owing to the policy of twitter , iam not posting the datset here.

Comment: You'll still want to check the formatting of the error messages. Copy/pasting the error message and then selecting it and pressing ctrl-K tends to produce good formatting on Stack Overflow.

Comment: "Expecting property name: line 1 column 1 (char 1)" sounds like what you are receiving isn't JSON at all. Can you print out the first few characters of the problematic data for debugging?

Comment: There you go. I validated the json using this link https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: @tripleee so should I be using json.dumps instead of json.loads in my python script?

Comment: Huh? No, `json.dumps` is for printing out JSON from a `dict`, you are clearly doing the opposite. I would still speculate that your JSON is somehow fragmented (perhaps like `[{ "stuff": {"more": "stuff"},` but no closing brackets? The fragment you posted looks vaguely like that) but there really is no direct way to tell from what you have posted so far.

Comment: okay will check with my dataset once more.As far as I know the json data I have is valid(dont worry about the brackets as i pasted only a few lines of it)

Comment: @tripleee I got it working. I just changed my code to collect twitter data. Thanks!